# Report that compares AD users by department attribute and their ResourceName in SCCM

Tags: powershell, active-directory, sccm

I am trying to develop a report for me and my team. The report looks at Active Directory and filters users based on department. I got that to work just fine. I then want those users to be cross referenced in SCCM to find their Resource Name devices. After they find the Resource Name devices I want their name and primary devices outputted and emailed to me in a report fashion. Note In the script below the $UserList is the list of AD users I already pulled based on the department FN(Finance). How can tell SCCM to take those users and find their primary device? Then how do I output both sets of data?

"$UserList = '\L007478\c$\temp\SCCM people.txt' ForEach ($User in $UserList) { $output = Get-CMUserDeviceAffinity -UserName $User

if ($output -eq $null) { $output -eq $null Write-Host "No Data was Found" } else { Write-Host $output }

}"

When you run Get-CMUserDeviceAffinity it will give you this data. All I really need is the ResourceName

SmsProviderObjectPath  : SMS_UserMachineRelationship.RelationshipResourceID=25172891
CreationTime           : 6/3/2020 10:11:33 AM
IsActive               : True
RelationshipResourceID : 25172891
ResourceClientType     : 1
ResourceID             : 16780388
ResourceName           : L007478
Sources                : {4}
Types                  : {}
UniqueUserName         : redgold\jknotts

Comment: `(Get-CMUserDeviceAffinity -UserName $User).ResourceName` would return `ResourceName` value based on your output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
$UserList = Get-Content '\\L007478\c$\temp\SCCM people.txt'
$output = ForEach ($User in $UserList) {
    $affinity = Get-CMUserDeviceAffinity -UserName $User
    $obj = "" | Select User,ResourceName # Create custom object with properties User and ResourceName
    $obj.User = $User # Set User property to $User
    if (!$affinity) { 
        $obj.ResourceName = 'No data was found' # Set ResourceName property
    } 
    else { 
        $obj.ResourceName = $affinity.ResourceName # Set ResourceName property
    }
    $obj # Output the custom object and store in collection $output
}

# output results
$output
# Output results to CSV
$output | Export-Csv output.csv -NoType
```

Since the `Get-CMUserDeviceAffinity` results contained a property called `ResourceName` that you want to retrieve, you can simply use the `.` member access operator. The syntax is `$variable.Property` or `(command).Property`.

Creating a custom object allows for custom properties.